# Question in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, Corollary 6.17

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

[image: ds,]

I got stuck in the underlined sentence.  I see that how Lemma 6.13 implies the existence of a vector $v_{N+2n+1}$ such that $v_{N+2n+1}$ is arbitrarily close to $e_{N+2n+1}$ and $\pi_{v_{N+2n+1}}~|_{\tilde M}~$ is an embedding. But what means that $\pi_{v_{N+2n+1}}~$ is arbitrarily close to $\pi_{e_{N+2n+1}}~$, and how can we show it?

Comment: There's a chain of "arbitrarily close" approximations all the way to the conclusion. So the statement of the corollary should suggest the meaning in the underlined sentence.

Comment: @epimorphic Then I think it should mean, that for every $\epsilon>0$, we have $|\pi_v(x)-\pi_e(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$, but I can't see why does should hold.

Comment: It might help to see the explicit formula for $\pi_v$. It is:
$$ \pi_v(w) = \left(w_1-\frac{w_{n+1}v_1}{v_{n+1}},\ldots,w_n-\frac{w_{n+1}v_n}{v_{n+1}}, 0\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The maps $\pi_v$ are linear maps $\mathbb R^{N+1}\to\mathbb R^N$ and thus lie in a finite dimensional vector space, which has only one reasonable topology. (My preferred interpretation for all "arbitrarily close" statements would be in topological terms.) To verify the statement, you can simply compute the matrix representations of $\pi_{e_{N+2n+1}}$ and $\pi_{v_{N+2n+1}}$ and observe that they are close to each other (in your preferred norm). The main point is that $\pi_v$ (more or less evidently) depends continuously on $v$ (just think about matrix entries).

Comment: It is clear that the matrix representation of $\pi_{e_{N+2n+1}}$ is the diagonal matrix $\text{diag}(1,1,...,1,0)$, but what is the matrix rep. of  $\pi_{v_{N+2n+1}}$ ?

Comment: What you want to do is to send a point $x\in\mathbb R^{N+1}$ to $x-\lambda v$, where $\lambda$ is chosen in such a way that $x-\lambda v$ has vanishing last coordinate. This allows you to compute the matrix explicitly, or you can deduce it from the comment of Steve D on your question.

Answer (score 3):

Since the statement of the corollary is that $f$ can be uniformly approximated by embeddings, the point is to get the embedding uniformly close to $f$. The phrase "$\pi_{v_{N+2n+1}}$ is arbitrarily close to $\pi_{e_{N+2n+1}}$" is shorthand for "given any $\varepsilon>0$, $v_{N+2n+1}$ can be chosen so that 
$$
\sup _{x\in \widetilde M} \big|\pi_{v_{N+2n+1}}(x) - \pi_{e_{N+2n+1}}(x)\big|<\varepsilon."$$